# How to sum up monthly values for 5 years? (To fit a univariate time serie)

Tags: r, time-series

So I have a tab separated value file that looks like below.

```
 Date       Value1
 2010-01-01    2 
 2010-01-02    0.2 
 2010-02-03    5 
 2010-02-07    2 
 2010-03-03    1 
 . . .
 2015-01-01    1.0
```

I need help with summing up all the values for each month.
So January in this case would be 2.2, February 7.0 etc.

I am currently working in R studio, and this needs to be done to my Time Series.
Is there any built-in command in R? Or could this be done easy in Java or Python?

The expected result would look like this:

```
 Date      Value1
 2010-01     2.2 
 2010-02     7  
 2010-03     1 
 . . .
 2015-01     1.0
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `sum(list_of_values)` after condensing the second column as a list.

Comment: Yeah I tried to merge the columns for each month with the merge command. It did not work at all. What could be a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In R this is a simple aggregation problem.

```
aggregate(Value1 ~ cbind(Date = format(as.Date(Date), "%Y-%m")), df, sum)
#      Date Value1
# 1 2010-01    2.2
# 2 2010-02    7.0
# 3 2010-03    1.0
# 4 2015-01    1.0
```

Or you can use `as.yearmon` from the zoo package for convenience. The advantage of `as.yearmon` is that its sorts in calendar order rather being just a string (like `format` gives), because base R doesn't have date class that doesn't contain a day

```
aggregate(Value1 ~ Date, transform(df, Date = as.yearmon(Date)), sum) 
#       Date Value1
# 1 Jan 2010    2.2
# 2 Feb 2010    7.0
# 3 Mar 2010    1.0
# 4 Jan 2015    1.0
```

Or you can convert your whole object to a `zoo` class

```
z <- read.zoo(df) 
aggregate(z, as.yearmon, sum)
```

Or if your data is big, you could combine with the `data.table` package too

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Value1 = sum(Value1)), by = list(Date = as.yearmon(Date))]
#        Date Value1
# 1: Jan 2010    2.2
# 2: Feb 2010    7.0
# 3: Mar 2010    1.0
# 4: Jan 2015    1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!